# decoding base64 websocket in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, request, decode

I'm using websocket-client, where I get binary responses (base64), where I can turn them into utf-8 without any problem. The current problem is that even converting the websocket response to utf-8, it seems to come compressed, I'm not sure because it shows unknown characters. I've tried in every way to unzip the answer using the zlib and gzip libraries, but it generates this error:

```
Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

My raw answer:

```
\x80\x00P\x12\x00\x03\x00\x01p\x12\x00\x02\x00\x01p\x12\x00\x02\x00\x04code\x04\x00\x00\x00\xc8\x00\ ronlinePlayers\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\xa4\x00\x01c\x08\x00\ronlinePlayers\x00\x01a\x03\x00\r\x00\x01c\x02\x01
```

My decoded answer (to base64):

```
gABQEgADAAFwEgACAAFwEgACAARjb2RlBAAAAMgADW9ubGluZVBsYXllcnMFAAAAAAAAAqQAAWMIAA1vbmxpbmVQbGF5ZXJzAAFhAwANAAFjAgE=
```

Same answer decoded, but using an online conversion site (ends up showing unknown characters):

```
�P � � p � � p � � code ���� 
onlinePlayers ������ � c � 
onlinePlayers� to � 
 � c
```

I don't know this kind of answer, I would like to understand what it is, if it's some kind of encryption, compression, or simply how to get the answer clean (with understandable characters).

Comment: I understand little about it, I've been venturing into requests for less than 1 year and I'm still learning a lot, I simply would like to understand what kind of answer this is, and how to get it cleanly (of course, if you don't need any kind of reverse engineering, which I'm totally against)